# Quartz Misfire - Concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, quartz-scheduler, terracotta, misfire-instruction

Quartz defined MISFIRE for following two scenarios:

1. Thread not available in POOL
2. Scheduler shutdown

If a job is "DisallowConcurrent" and a trigger is not executed because another job was being processed, does this trigger would be considered as misfire?

Assume MisfireThreshold to be zero for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the trigger would be considered as misfired and an appropriate misfire policy will be 
applied to the trigger.
You can verify this behavior by creating a trigger listener. With this, the triggerMisfired() method will be called for the misfired triggers.
Another point,
Putting the misfire threshold to zero would cause every trigger of you to be misfired as quartz do take some time (few milliseconds) to fire the trigger at the specified time of trigger.